# How to count the number of images in a pdf using R

Tags: r, image, pdf

I need to count the number of images (mostly graphs) in multiple pdf documents. Is there any way to do this in R? (at the moment the only solution I can find uses Perl: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518293)

Comment: You can shell out using `system()` and use `pdfimages` tool which is part of the **Poppler** package...

Comment: Define "images". The concept of "image" in a PDF is not as straightforward as you might think. The quickest path with R (for the moment) is going to be shelling out to `pdfimages` as @MarkSetchell indicated. What operating system are you running?